# Calling custom manager function in django templates

Tags: django, django-custom-manager

So I'm making an expense sheet django app and I'm stuck trying to render the Sum of all the inputted expenses.

I've created a custom manager to calculate the sum:

```
class ExpenseManager(models.Manager):
  def price_sum(self):
    return super(ExpenseManager, self).aggregate(total_price = Sum('price'))['total_price']
```

And added it to my model:

```
class Expense(models.Model):
  ...
  objects = models.Manager()
  price_object = ExpenseManager()
  ...
```

I know my manager works because when I execute it in the shell I get the correct sum of my expenses -- i.e. I put in `Expense.price_object.price_sum()` and I get back `Decimal('254.77')` -- but when I try to get that into my template it just shows up blank.

I've tried putting in my variable a couple different ways but none of it has worked, for example:

```
{{price_object.price_sum}}
```

or

```
{{expense.price_object.price_sum}}
```

or me getting desperate...

```
{% for p in expense.price_object %} {{p.price_sum}} {% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for p in expense.price_object.price_sum %} {{p}} {% endfor %}
```

but yeah... nothing ever shows up when I load the page. Can anyone help?

Comment: Was there ever a solution for this? Having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to define your manager method like this:

```
class ExpenseManager(models.Manager):
    def get_expenses(self):
        return super(ExpenseManager, self).get_query_set().aggregate(total_price = Sum('interval'))['total_price']
```

I just tried it and it calculated the sum in a template for me.

Comment: how did you call it in the template?

Comment: @sha256, As in Daniel Roseman's answer, you just need to pass a Model class object to the template.

Answer (score 1):

None of your template examples seem to be equivalent to what you did in the shell. In the shell, you correctly called the manager from the model class, `Expense`. That's exactly what you need to do from the template as well. You can't call it from a model instance, only the class, and I assume that the `expense` name you have there is an instance. You'll need to pass the *class itself* to the template context.

Comment: Sorry if this is basic, but how do you pass the class itself? currently in my view I pass `all_expenses = Expense.objects.all()` as the context as `{'expenses':all_expenses}` (I changed the variable from expense to expenses since it does account for all the expenses rather than one so that's not a problem in comparison to what I shared above)

Comment: A class is an object, like anything else. You can pass it in exactly the same way: `{'Expense': Expense}`.